# Creating a custom controller parameter automatically populated with HttpServletRequest?

Tags: spring-mvc

Using a strictly annotation-based/Java-only Spring MVC 3.2.2 configuration, I'm trying to create a controller method with a custom class (I'll call it `Context`) as a parameter. I want to have `Context` constructed with knowledge of the current `HttpServletRequest` and then passed along to the controller method. In essence, I want to create my own custom wrapper around the request object before it's sent to the controller. e.g. I want to accomplish this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public @ResponseBody
    String process(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Context context = new Context(request);
        ...
    }

}
```

automatically like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public @ResponseBody
    String process(Context context) {
        ...
    }

}
```

Is this possible? I looked into implementing a `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` as a `@Bean` in my `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` but I don't think that's the correct route to take. I've tried adding `@AutoWired` to `Context` (as a `@Bean`) to no avail as well. I imagine there's `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` or possibly in a `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`?

Answer (score 0):

`HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` and `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` is certainly a right way to achieve your goal.

In order to register custom argument resolver you need to make your `@Configuration` extend `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` and override its `addArgumentResolver()` method.